# How to have an Output for the angular dialog to tell the parent something

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

[image]
This is the first photo when I select something to edit and it is active
[image]
This is the second photo with the edited second object now this is selected but so it is the last selected. 
I have an Angular dialog, I can pass the data and everything but the problem it is so.
When I open the dialog for the selected object with id this is active and this is working, but when I open again the dialog with another object with another id then both of them are staying active and so makes for every object, it is any possible way to give a command when click cancel or save the dialog will reset the selected object id and when another one is selected only this should be active.

This is my code.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu-item" (click)="openValueItemEditDialog({valueItem: valueItem})">{{'button.#edit'|translate}}</div>
<div [class]="'name-block name-block-width-' + valueItem.level" [ngClass]="{'active': activeSelected === valueItem.id, 'critical': (impactanalyse$ | async) && valueItem.accumulatedImpact === 2 && valueItem.level !== 1, 'semi-critical': (impactanalyse$ | async) && valueItem.accumulatedImpact === 1 && valueItem.level !== 1, 'not-critical': (impactanalyse$ | async) && valueItem.accumulatedImpact === 0 && valueItem.level !== 1, 'selected-critical': (impactanalyse$ | async) && valueItem.level === 1}"
     (click)="setAllChildren()">

.name-block {
    @extend %common-block;
    @include center(false, true);
    @include justify-content(space-between);
    margin-left: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;

    &.active {
      z-index: 1950 !important;
    }

activeSelected: any = '';

openValueItemEditDialog(editOptions: EditOptions) {
        if (editOptions.valueItem) {
            this.store.dispatch(new SelectEditedViAction(editOptions.valueItem.id));
        }
        this.activeSelected = editOptions.valueItem.id;
        this.dialog.open(ValueItemEditDialogComponent, { data: editOptions, disableClose: false });
    }
```

This is the dialog

```
<mat-dialog-actions fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutAlign="end end" style="margin-right: 37px">
        <button *ngIf="!editOptions.planning && editedValueItem.technicalState == 0" (click)="save()" mat-dialog-close>Save</button>
        <button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
@Input() activeSelected: boolean
@Output() activeSelectedChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>()

save() {
        this.activeSelectedChange.emit(false);
```

Comment: Need more input from you. Better would be if you can share some screenshot.

Comment: @SunilSingh I will edit my question and add some pictures

Comment: @SunilSingh I have edited my question.

Comment: Now your question is pretty however you provided very limited code. Could you provide the more code html and ts.

Comment: @SunilSingh I appreciate what you said but I will add more code and hope you can help me, I added the code I don't have any functions more  just this what i have written